# Nmaping 127.0.0.1 vs. 192.168.1.107

Tags: networking, ssh, nmap

I was tinkering around with my computer and then I realized I forgot to install ssh, so I did install it and wanted to make sure that port 22 is open. So I nmaped my local IP `192.168.1.107`. And then I decided to nmap `localhost` and got 2 different results. I thought looping back would be the same result, but instead I got this.

My IP is 192.168.1.107

[image: IP]

Used: `sudo nmap 192.168.1.107`

[image: nmap LAN IP result]

Used: `sudo nmap 127.0.0.1`

[image: nmap localhost result]

Why are the results different?

Comment: It is up to the applications that open ports to decide which IPs they open them on. Not all will open on both addresses.

Comment: Ok Thanks!... So why some of them only open up to only localhost.. So what about my mail port?.... How can I open that to 192.168.1.107?

Comment: You'll need to look up the documentation for your mail service. I just remembered a further complication: some firewalls use `localhost` to intercept port traffic: they listen on the interface IP and transfer clean buffers to the applications, which are patched to listen on `localhost`. If you run `netstat -abn|more` you will have a better idea of what ports are open and to which programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program that opens a listening socket can decide which IP addresses the service should be available on.

A service that is listening on any address in `127.0.0.0/8` or `::1/128` is not (directly) reachable from outside the machine. This is suitable for hosting sensitive services without transport security and minimal authorization efforts.

As for your mail service: Unless you want to *receive* mails with your machine (highly unlikely) it doesn’t have to listen on the network. I’d even say it should not, because why create a possible vulnerability?

To expand a little on @AFH’s command: On GNU/Linux, the `netstat` command can be used to only show listening TCP connections:

netstat -tlpn

Meaning: -**-t**cp, -**-l**istening, -**-p**rogram, -**-n**umeric:

- Only TCP
- Only listening sockets (hides connections)
- Show listening program’s image name (requires root)
- Don’t resolve host names and port numbers

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to test how mailing works... I'll just find out how it supposed to work! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The loopback interface is intended to allow a network service to still run while other interfaces may not be available. This provides the system administrator the ability to still manage a network service via the console in the event of a system outage or potentially a network interface malfunctions.

Some services by default will bind a listener port across all interfaces (ie: 0.0.0.0:22 and 0.0.0.0:80 in your case) which includes the loopback interface as well. However note that it is bad practice to not properly configure a service once something is installed, you should ALWAYS change the default settings after you install a service.

However, In your case, you have a sshd network service, and webserver listening on a local address and these same services are listening on the localhost loopback interface as well. Should the network go down these services will still be up and accessible so one could gracefully shut them down via console.

The others are standard, one wouldn't neccessarily want smtpd, postgresql listening on the internet.  Having a smtp and postgresql service listening on an interface other than the loopback is just inviting spammers, or potential hackers to access your databases or other potential vulnerable improperly configured services.

Also presently within your present configuration, The webserver still has the ability to access the database (via loopback interface) on the local machine, should you have a website which may be running from a database. But external access to the database would not be there since that service isnt configured to listen on the local address (its only configured for loopback) interface.

Hopefully this makes some sense.

Also everyone hates spam. :)